# Bioconductor R packages are not found in the nodes of HPC

Tags: r, conda, slurm

Hello I am using R on a cluster that is run by SLURM. I am using conda  activated R environment and installing R packages with conda commands.  When I use  R in the login severer I can load Bioconductor Packages, e.g. `library(DESeq2)`. However, when I use one of the cluster nodes with:

```
srun --pty bash -i
```

and  try to load for example DESeq2, I get the following error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘Hmisc’

Package Hmisc is installed and I can load it when I use R in the login server.

This is my sessioninfo in the cluster node:

> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
> Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

> Matrix products: default
> BLAS/LAPACK: /data/home/me/anaconda3/envs/r_env/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.10.so

> Random number generation:
> RNG:     Mersenne-Twister
> Normal:  Inversion
> Sample:  Rounding

> locale:
> [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
> [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
> [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
> [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

> attached base packages:
> [1] grid      parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> [8] datasets  methods   base

Results of `.libPaths()` in the cluster node:

> /data/home/mygroup/myuser/anaconda3/envs/r_env/lib/R/library

Results of `conda list -n r_env hmisc`:

> packages in environment at /data/home/mygroup/myuser/anaconda3/envs/r_env: # # Name                    Version Build  Channel r-hmisc 4.4_1 r36h9bbef5b_0  conda-forge

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: everything looks ok. most likely you have to reinstall deseq2 again. because when you install that, it requires hmisc and would have required installation

Comment: Thank you @StupidWolf , Is there a difference if I Install  within R using `BiocManager::install(DESeq2)`   or using `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-deseq2` ? Thank you

Comment: if you do BiocManager::install(DESeq2), there might be some problems compiling some of the other dependencies.. you can try using conda first, if it works, at least that takes care of other conflicts etc